# How to print a snowman using Ruby

Tags: ruby, unicode

I want a placeholder for a single character string that I haven't implemented yet. How do I print a snowman in Ruby 1.9?

Currently, I can do

```
# coding: utf-8
puts "☃"
```

or

```
puts "\u2603"
```

but is it possible to use the "Index entries" field (mentioned [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2603/index.htm)) `snowy weather` or `SNOWMAN` or `weather, snowy` to get the character to print?

I am not using Rails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may download the [Name Index from unicode.org](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Index.txt) and parse the characters names into a Hash (or better a DB or similiar).

Then you can get it with normal data access functions.

Example:

```
# coding: utf-8
index = {}
File.readlines('Index.txt').each{|line|
  line =~ /(.*)\t(.*)$/
  index[$1] = $2.to_i(16).chr("UTF-8")
}

snowman = index['SNOWMAN']
p snowman #hope it works. My shell does not show the snowman
p "\u2603" == snowman #true
```

---

Edit:

There is a gem [unicode_utils](http://rubygems.org/gems/unicode_utils). With this gem you can use:

```
require "unicode_utils/grep"
p UnicodeUtils.grep(/^snowman$/) #=> [#<U+2603 "\u2603" SNOWMAN utf8:e2,98,83>]
```

Comment: +1. Maybe your machine is overheating and it melted the snowman as soon as it was printed.

Comment: @Eduardo That would explain the  puddle under my laptop ;)